# How to handle 404s in an observable request Angular

Tags: angular, observable

Problem i'm trying to fix:
I'm getting a lot of 404 not found in the console and I want to handle these.

I have these 2 methods in my angular code:

```
getUserByEmailAddress(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return this._http.get<User>("http://webapi.local/api/v2.0/users?email=" + email);
}


isEmailAddressAvailable(email: string) {
    var user: User;
    var response = this.getUserByEmailAddress(email);
    response.subscribe(
       usr => user == usr,
       error => user == undefined);
  if (user === undefined) {
  return true;
  }
  else {
  return false;
  }
}
```

This works as expected, when you call the end point if no user is found a 404 not found it returned.

**What I am trying to do**

I want to add a .catch() to the .get() request in getUserByEmailAddress()to handle these 404s and mask them from appearing in the console, however when i try to add it, I don't understand what i need to return for the observable, I've tried:

```
.catch(err => { return Observable.of(undefined)})
```

but i don't think this is quite right.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are trying to prevent it from appearing in the console ? if so i dnt think that is posible

Comment: @RahulSingh, yes I want to prevent it showing in the console

Comment: itg will come up in the console that is a browser feature which you cannot disable , you might have a interceptor but i feel that it will still show up in the console i am not sure 100% but , you can try an interceptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For handling the 404 error in my app what I do is in catch block

```
  if(err.status == 404)
         return  Observable.throw(new NotFoundError()) 
   else 
          return Observable.throw(new AppError(err))
```

but first you will have to make two classes called AppError which will be assigned to all the errors while notfoundError will be assigned to 404 error which will be an instance of AppError
IN apperror.ts

```
export class AppError {
    constructor(public err?:any){
        console.log(err);
       }
}
```

and in notFound.ts

```
import { AppError } from "./apperror";

export class NotFoundError extends AppError {

}
```

then in subscribe you can handle these error like this

```
response.subscribe(
       usr => user == usr,
      ((err:Error)=>{
        if(err instanceof NotFoundError){
          alert(err)
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead with either using map or do methods to check for the status code.

```
    getUserByEmailAddress(email: string): Observable<User> {
        return this._http.get<User>("http://webapi.local/api/v2.0/users?email=" + email).map(res => {
            if(res.status ==404) {
               throw new Error('This request has failed ' + res.status);
            } 
           else {
              return res.json();
          }
   }).catch(err =>  { 
      //custom logic goes here
      return Observable.throw(err); 
      });
    }
```

**snippet with 'do'**

```
getUserByEmailAddress(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return this._http.get<User>("http://webapi.local/api/v2.0/users?email=" + email).do(res => {
    if(res.status ==404) {
     //custom logic goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution will be http interceptor. Then you can check response of request an if it is 404 return Observable.empty()

https://angular.io/guide/http#logging

Comment: Thanks, how would I implement this, I'm not sure how to form the documentation